How to prevent the last column in ag-grid react from leaving blank space when resizing?

Following is the current settings for last column
{
  field: 'roles',
  headerName: 'User Roles',
  minWidth: 150,
  width: 240,
  sortable: true,
  cellDataType: 'object',
  filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
}

and following are the oprions in aggrid
<AgGridReact
    // rowData={tableData}
    ref={ref}
    columnDefs={tableColumns}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    rowSelection="multiple"
    suppressRowClickSelection
    pagination
    paginationPageSize={100}
    paginationPageSizeSelector={[10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 1000]}
    getRowStyle={getRowStyle}
    scrollbarWidth={8}
    tooltipShowDelay={0}
    tooltipHideDelay={2000}
    onRowDoubleClicked={handleDoubleClick}
    rowModelType="serverSide"
    onGridReady={tableData}
    // getRowId={getRowId}
    noRowsOverlayComponent={noRowsOverlayComponent}
    noRowsOverlayComponentParams={noRowsOverlayComponentParams}
  />

Is it possible to prevent the last column in table from resizing in this manner. I don't want to fully remove the resizing feature, only to prevent this empty space.
